# netflix zuul - how to change redirect url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have 2 application under my zuul.

application 1 sends to the browser redirect to application 2. exactly to: `x.y/abc/zzz`. i'd like zuul to modify this redirect and change it to a redirect to `x.y/`.

is it possible to do it using configuration or i need to implement custom filter?

Comment: I'd think a custom filter. There is some logic to change the host and port automatically, but not the path.

Comment: Is `x.y/abc/zzz` always consistent? I suppose you could configure that as it's own path with application2's serviceId or url associated to it, but that seems pretty heavy  handed. A post filter that rewrites the Location header seems like a better option.